# undefined control sequence won't go away

Tags: vim, undefined, control, sequence

I just installed LaTeX and have been using vim to edit a .tex document. no matter what I type the pdftex command it always hits up with the same issue. undefined control sequence.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
1.1 \Documentclass
                  {article}
```

the file is:

```
\Documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

this is some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: it should be `\documentclass` in lowercase.

Comment: Besides using `\documentclass`, you need `pdflatex`, not `pdftex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use capital "D"

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    this is some text
    
\end{document}
```

---

OUTPUT

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./texto.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-23>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./texto.aux) [1] (./texto.aux) )
Output written on texto.dvi (1 page, 264 bytes).
Transcript written on texto.log.
```

Comment: No file test.aux.
)
Runaway argument?
{document)
! File ended while scanning use of \end .
<inserted test>
                          \par
<*> test.tex

?

Comment: No error here.  I put the LaTeX output in the answer above. I used "latex <doc>.tex

Comment: do you ever post a question and wonder if maybe you might have brain damage when you see the answer?

Comment: more times than I'd like to admit